Schedule Kafka Consumer in Akka Streams to Run at Specific Times of Day
I have written a Kafka consumer using Akka Streams:
RestartSource.withBackoff(consumerResetProps(),
                () -> Consumer.committablePartitionedSource(consumerProps(), Subscriptions.topics(topics))
                        .mapAsyncUnordered(parallelism, pair -> pair.second()
                                .via(flow())
                                .runWith(Committer.sink(commiterProps()), system)))
        .toMat(Sink.ignore(), Keep.both())
        .run(system);

I want this consumer to be active only during specific times of the day (e.g., from 1 AM to 4 AM) and be turned off during the rest of the day. Does Akka Streams provide a built-in way to schedule this kind of behavior, or is there a recommended pattern to achieve this?

There's nothing within Akka Streams, but you can use the use the ActorSystem's scheduler (system.scheduler) to schedule the stream to run after a certain duration, so at application startup, you would have determine the amount of time until 1 AM and schedule the stream to run then.
Alpakka Kafka streams by default run forever, but you can use the Control object which the stream materializes as (note that if wrapping with restart logic, each restart will materialize a new Control: something similar to this would be required): calling drainAndShutdown will cause the consumer to not request any more messages from Kafka and wait for all messages in flight to be processed.  You can also use the scheduler to defer the drainAndShutdown call until 4 AM.
Note that it's possible to get more elaborate and cover more failure scenarios by encapsulating all this state in an actor (perhaps even a persistent actor, maybe run as a cluster singleton?), but this should be sufficient for a single-instance application (or if you don't mind every node in a cluster trying to start consuming (the Kafka consumer group can handle organization in that case)), where you can reasonably expect something like Kubernetes to restart.
